# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from R2DBC

Tags: oracle, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure from Spring Data R2DBC. I have currently set up querying either by annotation or R2DBC entity template and those work fine. However, I have not been able to call a proc with input/output parameters.

I saw some documentation mentioning support for procedure calls in R2DBC but have not found any concrete examples on how it is done. Any help or link to documentation or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc#procedural-calls

Comment: Yes, but how do I call a procedure? Eg my_proc(input1, input2, output1)

Comment: Sorry, phone linked me to the top of the page but now seeing the procedure section. Fantastic thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for how to do `procedural-calls` can be found in the readme on github for the `oracle-r2dbc` driver:

[procedural calls](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc#procedural-calls)